# Lord of The Simulation

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

[image: Lord of the Simulation]

Clues: [contextual images]

Instructions: Name That Actor

_ _ _ _ _ _ A _ _ _ _

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The title is a hint for 'matrix' (a simulation). This implies that the given hints are a matrix multiplication.

> Performing the matrix multiplication with the filled cells as 1 and empty as 0 gives this result for the first set:

> ```
> 0 1 1 0 0
> 0 1 0 1 0
> 0 1 1 0 0
> 0 1 1 0 0
> 0 1 0 1 0
> ```

> Which shows an 'R'. Repeating this process for the other matrix multiplications gives the hint 'Rivendell', a city in Lord of the Rings (which again is hinted by the title).

> The master of Rivendell is Elrond. The corresponding actor, and final answer to the puzzle, is Hugo Weaving.

(credits to cap for fixing this last bit).

OP Edit:

> Additionally, Hugo Weaving played Agent Smith in the Matrix, in which he multiplied like a computer virus. Thus we use matrix multiplication!